# Detecting if image is a cartoon or if it is a real person with OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv

I am trying to detect if an image is a cartoon or if it is a real person.  I have searched Google and implemented two algorithms mentioned, but neither can accurately predict if an image is a person taken by a camera or if it is a cartoon/anime character

Here is my script:

detectCartoon1 uses the Laplacian method to detect if an image is a person or not.  (I figured camera shots would be lower quality and thus this would easily work).  But it fails- it gives me tons of false positives.

detectCartoon2 uses a method mentioned by someone else on stack overflow.  It figures that after we apply the filter to the cartoon, there won't be many changes; but there will be a lot of changes if we apply a picture taken from a lower quality camera/webcam.  Again, tons of false positives.

I've been searching around Google for other methods- or trying to think of my own method, but I just can't think of anything.  I would greatly appreciate any help on this topic.

Thanks!

```
import cv2
import numpy

def detectCartoon1(imagePath):
    img_before = cv2.imread(imagePath)
    img_after = 0    

    gray = cv2.GaussianBlur(img_before, (3, 3), 0, 0, cv2.BORDER_DEFAULT)
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(gray, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    img_after = cv2.Laplacian(gray, cv2.CV_64F)
    img_after = cv2.convertScaleAbs(img_after)

    return numpy.mean(img_after)    

def detectCartoon2(imagePath):
    img_before = cv2.imread(imagePath)
    img_after = 0

    for i in range(1, 31, 2):
        img_after = cv2.bilateralFilter(img_before, i, i*2, i/2)

    img_after = cv2.cvtColor(img_after, cv2.COLOR_HSV2BGR_FULL)
    img_before = cv2.cvtColor(img_before, cv2.COLOR_HSV2BGR_FULL)

    return numpy.mean(img_before - img_after)

from os import listdir

for img in listdir('Save'):
    img = 'Save\\' + img
    dc1 = detectCartoon1(img)
    dc2 = detectCartoon2(img)
    print('Img: ' + img + ' detectCartoon1: ' + str(dc1) + ' detectCartoon2: ' + str(dc2))
```

Comment: did you find any answer ?

Answer (score 1):

Here is good paper on your issue: http://www.uv.es/~tzveta/invwork.pdf

Answer (score 0):

tl;dr: 8 year later answer - use [machine learning](https://keras.io/examples/vision/image_classification_from_scratch/)

I tried some of these methods myself and found that with a little tweaking opencv was "ok" at detection of cartoons. With just blurring and comparing histograms could get around 70% accuracy.

```
from pathlib import Path
from typing import Union

import cv2


def is_cartoon(image: Union[str, Path], threshold: float = 0.98) -> bool:
    # real people images:  79.5%     all: 2149 | cartoon: 440 | real: 1709
    # cartoon images:      59.4%     all: 481 | cartoon: 286 | real: 195

    # read and resize image
    img = cv2.imread(str(image))
    img = cv2.resize(img, (1024, 1024))

    # blur the image to "even out" the colors
    color_blurred = cv2.bilateralFilter(img, 6, 250, 250)

    # compare the colors from the original image to blurred one.
    diffs = []
    for k, color in enumerate(('b', 'r', 'g')):
        # print(f"Comparing histogram for color {color}")
        real_histogram = cv2.calcHist(img, [k], None, [256], [0, 256])
        color_histogram = cv2.calcHist(color_blurred, [k], None, [256], [0, 256])
        diffs.append(cv2.compareHist(real_histogram, color_histogram, cv2.HISTCMP_CORREL))

    return sum(diffs) / 3 > threshold
```

I tried something "simpler" but turns out is a lot more CPU intensive of counting the colors in the image. Then seeing how much of the image could be reproduced if only using the first 512 colors. This was around 75% accurate all told.

```
def is_cartoon_color_count(image: Union[str, Path], threshold: float = 0.3) -> bool:
    #real:     71%
    #cartoon:  80%
    # Much slower due to CPU overhead of color counting. Recommend multiprocess pool if using

    img = cv2.imread(str(image))
    img = cv2.resize(img, (1024, 1024))
    # img = cv2.bilateralFilter(img, 6, 250, 250)

    # Find count of each color
    color_count = {}
    for row in img:
        for item in row:
            value = tuple(item)
            if value not in color_count:
                color_count[value] = 1
            else:
                color_count[value] += 1

    # Identify the percent of the image that uses the top 512 colors
    most_common_colors = sum([x[1] for x in sorted(color_count.items(), key=lambda pair: pair[1], reverse=True)[:512]])
    return (most_common_colors / (1024 * 1024)) > threshold
```

But also, this is an old question. So I think a more modern way would be to use machine learning.

Building a training my own model based on Keras and tensorflow https://keras.io/examples/vision/image_classification_from_scratch/ I was able to get 95% accuracy with the same sample set (92% for cartoon detection, and over 99% for real images).